# Flatten the deep nested list of objects and create a csv. How?

Tags: json, python-requests

```
'[
       {
         "match_id": "386491", 
         "match_hometeam_score": "3",  
         "match_awayteam_score": "1", 
         "statistics": [
           {
             "type": "Shots on Goal", 
             "home": "5", 
             "away": "5"
           }
         ]
       }, 
       {
         "match_id": "386495",
         "match_hometeam_score": "1", 
         "match_awayteam_score": "2", 
         "statistics": [
           {
             "type": "Shots on Goal", 
             "home": "10", 
             "away": "7"
           }
         ]
       }
     ]'
```

I would like to flatten this json response. I had difficulties doing it since statistics is a list ob objects. Could you please help me with this?

So far I tried;

```
events_request = requests.get(events_url + api_key)
data = events_request.json()
data
df = pd.json_normalize(data,
                           sep="_",
                           record_path=[["statistics"]],                         
                          )
```

Then I tried,

```
json.dumps(data)
```

But what I had was not relevant to my expectation. What I expected is a result similar to a csv like this;

```
match_id,match_hometeam_score,match_awayteam_score,stattype,stathome,stataway
0,386491,3,1,Shots on goal,5,5
1,386495,1,2,Shots on goal,10,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get required structure, you can use this script (it will save the data to `data.csv`):

```
import json
import pandas as pd


data = '''[
       {
         "match_id": "386491", 
         "match_hometeam_score": "3",  
         "match_awayteam_score": "1", 
         "statistics": [
           {
             "type": "Shots on Goal", 
             "home": "5", 
             "away": "5"
           }
         ]
       }, 
       {
         "match_id": "386495",
         "match_hometeam_score": "1", 
         "match_awayteam_score": "2", 
         "statistics": [
           {
             "type": "Shots on Goal", 
             "home": "10", 
             "away": "7"
           }
         ]
       }
     ]'''


data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'statistics', ['match_id', 'match_hometeam_score', 'match_awayteam_score'])

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

The content of `data.csv`:

```
,type,home,away,match_id,match_hometeam_score,match_awayteam_score
0,Shots on Goal,5,5,386491,3,1
1,Shots on Goal,10,7,386495,1,2
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]